# What does the diner say here?

Tags: oral

What does the diner say at the 16-second mark in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XO-oXz0XGUo)?

Waiter: Un petit fromage ou on vous apporte la liste des desserts ?

Diner: ______

Waiter: Oui ou non ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe he says *c'est qu'il y a trop*, pronounced *c'est qu'y a trop*.

The diner is trying to complete his sentence but is constantly interrupted:

> Le problème avec les grand restaurants, c'est qu'il y a trop de service.